# После перезагрузки приходится переписывать routing

Tags: маршрутизация, centos, сеть

Подскажите кто знает, куда внести данные в CentOS 6:

---

*# route add -host 172.xxx.xxx.10   gw 172.xxx.xxx.1*

*# route add -host 172.xxx.xxx.110  gw 172.xxx.xxx.1*

*# route add -host 172.xxx.xxx.1    gw  172.xxx.xxx.1*

---

*# route add default dev ppp0*

или

*# route add default gw 10.10.0.2*

---

т.к при перезагрузке либо-же при включении приходится каждый раз вносить эти данные вручнуючерез терминал.Это не сложно и не тяжело но немного напрягает.И второе ,каким образом создать кнопку запуска на запуск скрипта "pppd call xxxxx".Скрипт находится в папке /etc/ppp/peers.Все это дело запускается от root

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаток centos, но попробуйте добавить маршрут в /etc/rc.conf, если такой файл существует.

Comment: Таковой файл не найден

Answer (score 1):

[@sergarcada](/users/185/sergarcada) почти прав

У вас есть два пути:

1. Добавить все маршруты разом в файл `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`
2. Создать файл с маршрутами, дать ему права на исполнение и прописать к нему путь в `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

В `/etc` обычно валяется линк на `rc.local`, можно править оттуда

Comment: Отличный ответ,спасибо сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Все оказалось значительно проще - создал файл /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1 (связь у меня через eth1),выставил ему права на выполнение,внес необходимые данные,подкорректировал файл ifup-routes,и... чудо,все сохраняется и работает. Спасибо всем кто помогал в этом вопросе.Осталось найти как сделать кнопку запуска для файла pppd /etc/ppp/peers/call xxxx  от root.Может кто подскажет?

Comment: Да, или так. Создайте лучше новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Не юзал Cent в OpenSUSE это все в /etc/sysconfig/network

Comment: который непосредственно файл?

Comment: Поднимать роуты через rc.local или boot.local не совсем правельное решение